# How to paste from an external source on VI/VIM

Tags: command-line

I'm using VI right now to create a php file in AWS. I wanted to know if there was any way I could paste (as in copy/paste) an array from another file into my VI on PuTTY.

The program is supposed to iterate over an array of addresses to parse them but I can't seem to figure out an efficient or easy way to upload the list of addresses.

Here's what the array looks like:

[image: Snippet of the array]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Shift`+`Insert` or right-click -> paste like you normally do? As long as vi is in 'insert' mode.

Alternatively upload the file and open it in the same vim instance (`:split`, `:vsplit` or `:tabedit`), `y,<number of lines>,y` to copy and `p` to paste.

To navigate between tabs type `gt`, between split panes use `Ctrl`+`W`,

Comment: Also the vim wiki is a good source of information, Google is your friend :)

Comment: the right click didn't work but the upload and split did.

Comment: Instead of opening the file, yanking, pasting... just do `:r $file`.